# How do text editors calculate cursor position when using a variable width font?

Tags: algorithm, editor

I can't find any information on the subject. Is there a common algorithm for this or does it differ from editor to editor?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I assume you want to convert mouse position in `[pixels]` into cursor position in `[char]` and back.

Rendering API usually provides functions returning text width and height in pixels instead of rendering it. This can be used to convert between character and pixel position.

`(cx,cy) [char] -> (mx,my) [pixels]` can be done directly for example like this (VCL):

```cpp
mx = TextWidth(Substring(line[cy],1,cx))
my = FontHeight*cy
```

Where `line[]` holds the lines of the editor. `TextWidth`is tight to specific visual object Canvas where you rendering the text so it should be `object->Canvas->TextWidth(...` and `FontHeight` should be the line height of your editor in pixels.

The reverse conversion `(mx,my) [pixels] -> (cx,cy) [char]` is more tricky. The `cy` coordinate is simple division however `cx` must be iterated. For ordinary text windows is simple linear `O(n)` search enough (getting string width in pixels so test first single char then first 2 then first 3 ... until `x >= mx`).

However once the line is too long you can speed up this by using binary search. Another option is using avg character width divide your mouse position by it to get approximate character position and then simply search linearly from that position.

Beware once you start using Unicode encoding like UTF-8 and or esc codes like tabulator you need to keep in mind that avg character width is not always a good approach.

Here example of linear search:

```cpp
cy = my/FontHeight
for (cx=0;;)
  {
  if (line[cy].Length()<=cx) break; // end of line reached
  if (mx<TextWidth(Substring(line[cy],1,cx))) break;
  cx++;
  }
```

Of coarse if you do not use VCL you need to find the `TextWidth` counterpart in your environment. The same goes for `Substring`. Beware code examples was not tested and written directly in answer editor so there might be errors (like syntax and off by one)

Anyway modern programming environments have editor components ready to use (like `TMemo` in VCL) which has all of this functionality already implemented.

Comment: It's a little less complicated than I thought. Thank you very much!